# Multiple socket clients gets disconnected [socket.io]

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, chat, disconnect

Lets say..I have a two clients connected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/90IlV.png

So as soon as i refresh any one of the browser both clients get disconnected..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZx99.png

and I have written code to remove socket if of the user that gets disconnected.

```
    let userId = socket.request._query['userId'];
            socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                 console.log("disconnect: ", socket.id);
                User.removeSocketId(userId, (err, res) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
//updated code and found this emit was causing the issue, without this code everything work fine.
                    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-list-response',{
                        error : false ,
                        userDisconnected : true ,
                        socketId : socket.id
                    });     
                });
            });
```

So because of this socket ID of both clients gets removed.

Is there any way to stop that multiple disconnection ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the `User.removeSocketId` function source code?

Comment: I need to see more code. what I guess is happening is that the variable userId is always a reference to the last user that connected. You need to find a a better way to save the the userId value. Might i suggest socket.userId = socket.requrest._query['userId']. Then you can call User.removeSocketId(socket.userId, (err,res)...

Comment: @gnuns
module.exports.removeSocketId = function(idObj, callback){
 User.findByIdAndUpdate(idObj, 
  {$set : {socketID: "", onlineStatus: "N"}}, 
 callback);
}

Comment: @magreenberg, thanks for suggestion.will check om that.

Comment: Found the code that was causing the issue..I have updated in above code, now as I need to emit the event, I will have to get socket ID of client that gets disconnected and emit to all other clients....anyways thanks guys.